# Generating random numbers and displaying them in a div after the page loads (DOM js)

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to generate random number and display it in a div every time when the page loads. The problem is it doesn't work and on top of that the js console in the browser has a problem with some of the tokens. I think they're right (code below) but even if I try to change them, it still says the same thing. Do you know where is the problem? Thank you!

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  function generateRandomNumber();
  document.querySelector("#text").textContent = "The number is " + rnum + ".";
})

function generateRandomNumber() {
  var rnum = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1);
  return rnum;
}
```

```html
<div id="count">
  <div id="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You needed to change `function generateRandomNumber();` to `var rnum= generateRandomNumber();` inside the eventListener

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an issue with the way you were calling the function `generateRandomNumber()` you do not need to use the `function` keyword before calling a JavaScript function. Also the variable `rnum` was not declared before using it.

```html
<div id="count">
        <div id="text">
        </div>
 </div>

<script>

 window.addEventListener('load', function() {
       var rnum = generateRandomNumber (); //rnum was not defined here
       document.querySelector("#text").textContent = "The number is "+ rnum + "."; 
 })
 function generateRandomNumber () {
       var rnum = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1);
       return rnum;
 }

</script>
```

Comment: Less a typo more a misunderstanding on how to call a function.

Comment: Still not really worth keeping for the posterity